# Python Remove Words from String up to next spaces

Tags: python

i have that code, to remove words from a string. But the problem is, if the word has more letters at it, it doesnt removed. Its only removing when its matches 100%.

Any ideas how i can change it, so it also removes "NAMEde" also when i just type name in my list? Same on "do", when there is "dos", it needs to removed  cause "do" is in that word.

```
name = 'NAMEde What if i dos'
stopwords = ['name', 'do']
querywords = name.split()

resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print(result)
```

Comment: What result is expected for `name="What if I don't"` ?

Answer (score 1):

To remove words from a string up to the next space, you can modify your code as follows:

```python
import re

name = 'NAMEde What if i dos'
stopwords = ['name', 'do']

# Create a regular expression pattern to match the stopwords while ignoring case
pattern = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(stopwords) + r')\w*\b'

# Use re.sub to replace the matched stopwords with an empty string
result = re.sub(pattern, '', name, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(result)
```

This code uses regular expressions to find and replace the stopwords in the input string, taking into account that they can occur as part of larger words. The \b in the pattern ensures that the stopwords are matched as whole words, and re.IGNORECASE makes the matching case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` function to check for simplified partial matching:

```
querywords = 'NAMEde What if i dos'
stopwords = ['name', 'do']

result = ' '.join(w for w in querywords.split()
                  if not any(s_w in w.lower() for s_w in stopwords))

print(result)
```

---

```
What if i
```